# What's the hardware spec for Google Colaboratory?

Tags: hardware, google-colaboratory

I load some (not so) big data into it. A compressed file at 9GB. It can't decompress because the disk space is not enough.

What's the current hardware spec? What's the disk size?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can see the disk information using a command like `!df -h`. To see CPU specs, `!cat /proc/cpuinfo`. For memory, `!cat /proc/meminfo`.

Here's an example notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1_x67fw9y5aBW72a8aGePFLlkPvKLpnBl

**Edit: Colab now offers a [Pro version](https://colab.research.google.com/signup) which offers double the amount of disk available in the free version.**

Answer (score 27):

Here I run some test.

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1dint4ly-7h8Trw0XRJ1uhC_VKe_wDJfY

In short:

- n1-highmem-2 instance
- 2vCPU @ 2.2GHz
- 13GB RAM
- 100GB Free Space
- idle cut-off 90 minutes
- maximum 12 hours

2020 Update:

- GPU instance downgraded to 64GB disk space.

Comment: what does idle cut-off and maximum time mean?

Comment: @laltin If you close the browser, it will stop in 90 minutes. If you open the browser, it will stop in 12 hours.

Comment: I can use it only 12 hours?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam you can save the result (like every hour), then restart training from your last checkpoint.

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich kindly provide the code or something to store and restore the model in case my model takes more than 12 hours to train...

Comment: Sometimes I see 2.2GHz chip speed and sometimes I see 2.3GHz.

Comment: "GPU instance upgraded to 350 GB" of free space?

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich How can I save my model in tensorflow every 30 minutes? Any sample code?

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich How did you found the idle cut-off time? Your colab notebook does not return a value for that?

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich It seems it is not always the case. I am on MacOS and have my browser Chrome open and have my computer set to never sleep ( But I lock it ), however, after 90 minutes it tells me Runtime disconnected.

Comment: Thanks @korakot for these updated specs. When you say “GPU instance upgraded to 350 GB” is that the GPU RAM or hard disk?

Answer (score 23):

I ran few tests and found ,

GPU: 1xTesla K80 , compute 3.7, having 2496 CUDA cores , 12GB GDDR5  VRAM

CPU: 1xsingle core hyper threaded Xeon Processors @2.3Ghz i.e(1 core, 2 threads)

RAM: ~12.6 GB Available

Disk: ~33 GB Available

you can see it here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/151805XTDg--dgHb3-AXJCpnWaqRhop_2

Comment: Thanks for the code. Is it possible to find the information about OS if the VM?

Comment: Hi @Anirudh Chandupatla, when you say “2496 CUDA cores”, does that mean there are 2496 GPU cores? I have read somewhere that the free version of Google Colab only has a single (ie. 1) GPU core, though I am not sure how updated this is

Comment: @Leockl Single GPU has multiple CUDA cores. It's like single CPU has multiple cores (around 4). Also, using single CUDA core simply does not make sense, as that would make GPU slower than CPU.