# 77Giga data load in Google.colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, pydrive

I have a tar.gz file that contains 77 gigabyte of data and i am trying to load it into my Google.colab. But i get

> "Runtime died"

error and then it automaticly restarts. Please can anyone help?

Comment: Google Cloud Datalab is the paid version of jupyter-as-a-service on Google Cloud Platform.  Colab is the free one.  Colab runs on a VM of type n1-highmem-2 and those cost $60/mo normally.  Thats without the 200GB disk and the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Google colab is only for research purposes or for educational purposes and not for prolonged training. It has limitations most important being memory. 
If you run :

```
!df
```

You will find that memory that runtime is allocated is about 45-50 GB (47GB, to be precise), you are trying to load 77 GB, don't you expect runtime to die?

If you want to use, try splitting your data into small parts and train on them, delete and reload from g-drive and repeat.

See this answer for more info on runtime hardware

[What's the hardware spec for Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805170/whats-the-hardware-spec-for-google-colaboratory)