# Is there an optimized way to convert a numpy array to fortran order when using memmaps

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

I have a memmapped numpy array:

```
arr = np.load("a.npy", mmap_mode='r')
```

It is bigger than my memory. For my further computation I need it in fortran order instead of C. So I can use `np.asfortranarray` to convert it and then use `np.save` to store it in a new file.

However when I do this my memory usage increases proportionally to the input and as such makes me think that an object is being created in memory, I would like it to be fully a, file to file interaction.

How can I convert `a.npy` into fortran order without having the full object in memory?

---

For example, I have array:

```
arr =array([[1, 2],
            [3, 4]])
```

This is stored on disk as follows by numpy:

```
fortran_order: False
01 02 03 04
```

I can do the following transformations:

1

```
np.asfortranarray(arr)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

saved as:

```
fortran_order: True
01 03 02 04
```

2

```
np.asfortranarray(arr.T)
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

saved as:

```
fortran_order: True
01 02 03 04
```

3

```
arr.T
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

saved as:

```
fortran_order: True
01 02 03 04
```

`arr.T` only converts the high level accessiblity, I need the on disk ordering to be swapped (this will help with my overall task by keeping the array indexing with C in cache). This can be done by calling `np.asfortranarray` without `arr.T` however this incurs a full data copy instead of a transposed view being created and written in the transposed order.

Comment: If you want a contiguous Fortran array, then this is not possible since the array is stored contiguously using the row-major ordering while Fortran is column major. If this is fine to get a non-contiguous Fortran array (memory view of a C array with strides), then this is possible but the access will be inefficient for native Fortran accesses, and fast for native C one. The conversion to a contiguous Fortran array require a (mandatory) copy: data needs to be reordered in memory.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73483728) related post might help you to understand how things works (though the context is different).